# function in jquery does not work after it get redirected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am trying to run a function(that shows a flash message) in a jquery function after I do the window.location.href to redirect to a new page but it does not work. Even the console.log("confirmnewpage") does not show up at the new page. I have already tested to confirm that the function showFlashMessage(msg) works, it just doesn't work inside the click function. Is there any way to do it so the flashmessage or any other function could run after it gets redirected to a new page? By the way I am using django as my backend if that matters.

Thanks

my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/$', ContactView.as_view(), name='Contact'),
]
```

My html

```
<form class='db' action='{% url 'Contact' %}' msg='Hello John!' method="post" style="display: inline">{% csrf_token %}
<input class='btn btn-success buttonspace' type="submit" value="Home">
</form>
```

my javascript

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        {% block jquery %}


          function showFlashMessage(message) {
            var template = "<div class='container container-alert-flash'>" + 
            "<div class='col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1'> " + 
            "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>" + 
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>" +
            "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>" 
            + message + "</div></div></div>"
            $("body").append(template);
            $(".container-alert-flash").fadeIn(500);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
              $(".container-alert-flash").fadeOut(500);
            }, 5000);
          }

          $(".db").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault()

          var Url = $(this).attr("action");
          var msg = $(this).attr("msg");

          $("#dc").fadeIn("300")
          $("#dc").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'fade' }, 
            hide: { effect: 'fade' },
            buttons:{
              1:{       
                id:"close",
                text:"Confirm",
                click: function(){
                  console.log("confirm") 
                  window.location.href = Url

                  console.log("confirmnewpage") //This does not work.
                  showFlashMessage(msg) //This does not work.

                  $(this).dialog("close")
                },
                class: "buy-btn"
              },
              2:{       
                id:"close",
                text:"Cancel",
                click: function(){
                  console.log("cancel")
                  $(this).dialog("close")
                },
                class: "cancel-btn"
              }
            }
          })
          })


        {% endblock %}
    })

 </script>
```

Comment: Code in current page is gone after a redirect. New page knows nothing about the old page code. Anything after you call that redirect will also be ignored

Comment: I would pass a parameter with the redirect, that parameter should trigger the pop-up function to work when the page loads.

Comment: @user3655574 You can share the html templates and the two js codes, the page that activates the message and the page where the message is displayed?

Comment: Hi Brian, I added the url.py fyi, activating the link will take the user to a contact page through {% url 'Contact' %} Ginger Squirrel/charlietfl, yeah thanks that got me on the track to look for passing the parameters with redirect. Is there a way to still pass the tag "msg" which is in the original form since it is being redirected a new function is used. Thanks